# Encrypting Signed Data

Tags: encryption

I'm submitting a file with the sensitive data to a 3rd party, could anyone explain what is the point in signing it and encrypting at the same time? Does just encrypting not verify my identity (the 3rd party requested it to be signed and then encrypted)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sign with your private key. Signature is proof of origin, it proves that you were in possession of the private key therefore the data must be from you, and the data was not altered.

You encrypt with the destination public key. This is to ensure that only the destination can decrypt it.

As you see, the signature and encryption serve different purposes.

Comment: there is also a case when you sign and encrypt using symmetric keys, but that applies almost always to data in transit, typical example being SSL/TLS. There the signature is to prevent tampering of encrypted data, because decryption does not detect tampering per-se (is only the fact that the decrypted data is usually garbage that shows tampering), and there can be attacks that tamper the encrypted data in a way that yields valid decrypted data, Adding an HMAC signature detects this.

Answer (score 1):

Signing is putting your signature on a letter, and encrypting is putting the letter in an envelope. The envelope keeps other people from reading the letter. The signature proves that you wrote the letter.

Additionally, you sign and then encrypt, in that order, because if you instead put the letter in the envelope first, and then sign the envelope, this doesn't really prove that you wrote letter. You could argue in front of a judge that you didn't get to see the letter before the envelope was sealed.

Finally, you should not use the same key for both signing and encrypting. There are cryptographic reasons, but another, simpler reason is that the key that you use for encrypting can be held in escrow by other people (for example, the company you work for) to have access to the contents of all of your envelopes if needed, but the key you use for signing should only be given to people you would trust to legally sign in your place, as if a power of attorney.